# How to get the codepage currently used in local computer?

Tags: python, codepages

In a Python 3.8 script, I'm trying to retrieve the codepage which is currently used in my computer (OS: Windows 10).

Using `sys.getdefaultencoding()` will return the codepage used in Python ('utf-8'), which is different from the one my computer uses.

I know I can get this information by sending the `chcp` command from a Windows Console:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1316]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Me>chcp
Active code page: 850

C:\Users\Me>
```

Wonder if there's an equivalent in Python libraries, without need of spawning sub-processes, reading stdout and parsing the result string...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chcp` command uses  [`GetConsoleOutputCP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsoleoutputcp) Windows API under the hood to *get the number of active console code page*. You could call the same function from python by using
`ctypes` module([`windll.kernel32.GetConsoleOutputCP`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#loading-dynamic-link-libraries)).

```
>>> from ctypes import windll
>>> import subprocess
>>>
>>> def from_windows_api():
...     return windll.kernel32.GetConsoleOutputCP()
...
>>> def from_subprocess():
...     result = subprocess.getoutput("chcp")
...     return int(result.removeprefix("Active code page: "))
...
>>> from_windows_api() == from_subprocess()
True
```

Comment: Nicely done; a heads-up for those running Python v3.8 and below: replace `removeprefix("Active code page: ")` with `.replace("Active code page: ", "")` to make the sample code work.

Comment: On my platform, the output of `chcp` is localized: `Aktive Codepage: 850.` I used a regex to extract the codepage number: `return int(re.search(r"\d+", result).group())`